# Consuming a SOAP web service using end point

Tags: java, soap

I have a requirement whereby I am required to consume a SOAP web service, via a specific end point.What is the best way of consuming this:

1)Generate Java classes using wsimport and deploy them in higher environments.

2)Generate XSD files manually for this web service or automatically using some tool,and let ant generate Java classes.

3)Try to get the WSDL file from this end point and then place it in my directory,and then let ant generate Java classes.

Comment: The third option is probably best.  The WSDL is the authoritative definition of the SOAP service and its operations.

Comment: @VGR, how do I get the WSDL file for the end point, if the person only shares the service end point?

Comment: In many cases, appending `?wsdl` to the base URL of a service will return the service’s WSDL.

Comment: @VGR,can I save this file with any name and wsdl extension?

Comment: Yes.  The file name will not affect the generation of classes.